# Colorbox and php form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have a simple form page and i want to when the form is submit show the response message which came from my process.php in to colorbox. Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with this

```
$("#link").colorbox({ inline:true, href: "#msg"});

$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: $('intpu[type="text"]').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
          $("#link").click(); // My mistake $("#link").colorbox(); This doesn't work
          return false;
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Your html

```
<form name="exam" method="post">
          <input size="60" type="text" name="quote" />
          <input type="submit"> 
</form>
<a id="link" style="display:none"></a>
<div id="msg" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: sorry but i'm using post method these are my examples

<form action="process.php" name="exam" method="post">
<input size="60" type="text" name="quote" /><input type="submit">


and this my process.php ......    if(mysql_query($query))
    {
    echo "saved bla bla";

how can i show "saved bla bla" in colorbox?

Comment: With the code i wrote, when you click the button, it will make a request to process.php and the "echo" on that page will print in "div#msg", then the colorbox is going to appear showing the "div#msg". I hope you can understand me. Jaja

Comment: ok thanks i understand u but it's not working message is saved in db but colorbox is not opened.